# How to make sure users only get to DetailView, Listview and UpdateView their own created objects

Tags: django, django-views

I've created a simple app where logged in users can can submit a session for a conference, view the results of their submission, view a list of their submissions, and edit their submissions (they should not have access to other users' submissions). I'm using django's class-based views (CreateView, DetailView, ListView, UpdateView).

I'm struggling with the permissions however. All the views, except updateview, work but if I type in the url directly using a non-logged in username I can see their submissions.

I also suspect that the permissions is the same reason I can't get the updateview to work.

What am I missing? And is there a better way to avoid using usernames and slugs in the Url? I can't seem to find any examples or tips in how to do this type of thing. I'm a beginner so probably miss some understanding of the fundamentals here and there.

I've tried to understand how the User model works because there I did manage to find a way to create, view and edit user details in a protected way. I relied on function views there though and can't seem to apply that approach to the submission app.

models.py

```
class Hsession(models.Model):

submitter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="submittersessions", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
submission_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
session_title = models.CharField("session title", max_length=40, default='')
session_description = models.TextField("session description", max_length=350, default='')
slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.session_title)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("submission:detail-single", kwargs={"username": self.submitter.username, "slug": self.slug})
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.CreateSubmission.as_view(), name="create"),
    path("by/<username>/<slug>",views.SubmissionDetail.as_view(),name="detail-single"),
    path("by/<slug>/edit",views.EditSubmission.as_view(), name="edit"),
    path("by/<username>/",views.SubmissionList.as_view(), name="list"),
    ]
```

views.py

```
class CreateSubmission(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):

    fields = ('session_title', 'session_description', 'subject_category')
    model = models.Hsession

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.submitter = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

class SubmissionList(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):

    model = models.Hsession
    template_name = "submission/user_hsession_list.html"

    def get_queryset(self):

        try:
            self.hsession_submitter = User.objects.prefetch_related("submittersessions").get(
                username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username")
            )
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
        else:
            return self.hsession_submitter.submittersessions.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["hsession_submitter"] = self.hsession_submitter
        return context

class SubmissionDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):

    model = models.Hsession

     def get_queryset(self):
         queryset = super().get_queryset()
         return queryset.filter(
            submitter__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username")
         )

class EditSubmission(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    model = models.Hsession
    fields = ('session_title', 'session_description', 'subject_category')
    template_name = 'submission/hsession_update.html'
    success_url = 'submission/hsession_detail.html'
```

forms.py

```
class UserSubmissionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Hsession
        fields = ['session_title','session_description', 'subject_category']

class EditSubmissionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Hsession
        fields = ['session_title','session_description', 'subject_category']
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `UserPassesTestMixin` like this

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class EditSubmission(UserPassesTestMixin,LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
   model = models.Hsession
   fields = ('session_title', 'session_description', 'subject_category')
   template_name = 'submission/hsession_update.html'
   success_url = 'submission/hsession_detail.html'

   def test_func(self):
       //should return true if he have access
       if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
          slug = self.kwargs['slug']
          obj = self.model.objects.get(slug=slug)
          login_user = self.request.user
          return login_user.pk == obj.submitter.pk
       else:
           return False
```

for more information [UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin)

Comment: thanks for that. it now throws up 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'args' - in the line 'username = self.request.kwargs['username']. so I suspect there's another problem in the way i'm accessing 'username' from the user model

Comment: great progress thx. detail and listview now block access if I try access using another username ("fobidden"). but the update view now always throws a forbidden screen even though i'm logged in. suspect this is the same underlying problem that blocked it earlier.

Comment: the idea behind `test_func` is that it has return either true or false., based on your condition., so debug query

Comment: You can pass in LoginRequiredMixin before UserPassesTestMixin and you won't have to check if the user is authenticated in your test_func().

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class EditSubmission(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, generic.UpdateView):
   model = models.Hsession
   fields = ('session_title', 'session_description', 'subject_category')
   template_name = 'submission/hsession_update.html'
   success_url = 'submission/hsession_detail.html'

    def test_func(self):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == self.object.user:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I'm using "UserPassesTestMixin" like this and it is working.